# Send a notification when an Amazon S3 Bucket is created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, notifications, amazon-sns

How to send a notification when an Amazon S3 bucket is created? When I searched, all examples are about object creation. Can you please redirect me?

Comment: Event Bridge will contain information about such kind of management events and will let you subscribe to them.

Comment: I tried but did not work

Comment: what did you try, what did not work?

Comment: I tried this one: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-s3-object-created-tutorial.html

I followed all the steps but did not notify when I created a new bucket.

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive notifications when a bucket is created, you have to rely on CloudTrail API.

In EventBridge, you can create an event pattern like this:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["CreateBucket"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. There are steps I did:

1. Eventbridge > Rules > Create Rule
2. Rule name defined
3. Build event Pattern: AWS events or EventBridge partner events
    Creation method > Use pattern form > Event Pattern : Cloud Trail - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
    Edit Pattern and paste the code you send.
4. Target > Sns target I have created
5. Create

Is that something wrong?

Comment: no, that should work. I tried myself and it worked.

Comment: do i need to create a trail in cloudtrail?

Comment: Can you please write step by step?

Comment: Here is the link. I suggest to search yourself otherwise you won't achieve anything with AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks, dude but don't worry, i can achieve :) you don't need to be this rude after only suggesting one little thing.